The minimum possible value of $\sqrt{58-42x}+\sqrt{149-140\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$ WITHOUT the use of calculus
My friend recently gave me another problem that, humiliatingly enough, I cannot seem to solve. Find the minimum of the function (without the use of calculus) $$\sqrt{58-42x}+\sqrt{149-140\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$ When $x\in[-1,1]$.
My thought process goes as follows:
The first thing that I tried was a trig substitution. Since there is a $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$, I decided to do $x=\cos(\theta)$, simplifying it to $$\sqrt{58-42\cos\left(\theta\right)}+\sqrt{149-140\sin\left(\theta\right)}$$ However, I do not know how to continue with this problem, one person hinted towards the use of LOC(Law Of Cosines), and using geometry. But I do not know where to apply it. If you are willing to help, I would be grateful.

Just look  for x=0 and x=1

@trula : why? Actually, the minimum is not 0, nor 1.

Hint: If you let $x=\sin\theta$ instead of $\cos\theta$ then $149-140\cos\theta=10^2 +7^2-2(10)(7)\cos\theta$.

And indeed the other term you have is $7^2+3^2 - 2(3)(7)\cos\theta$. Perhaps a triangle with sides 3, 7, 10?

They can be represented as moduli of vectors

Does this answer your question? Find Minimum value of $\sqrt{58-42x}+\sqrt{149-140\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ - found using an Approach0 search. Note the question doesn't specify not using calculus, and most of the answers do, but this answer doesn't, with it being fairly similar to Brian's answer here.

FYI, the search also shows the AoPS thread 2017 General #9, where the solution in its Post #$2$ is fairly similar to Brian's here, and dan_fulea's in the proposed duplicate. There's also the AoPS thread A cool minimization problem, but where the $42x$ is replaced with $40x$, but several of the later posts suggest it's a typo, with it to be $42x$ instead.

First, I'd note that
$$\sqrt{58-42|x|}+\sqrt{149-140\sqrt{1-|x|^{2}}} \leq \sqrt{58-42x}+\sqrt{149-140\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$
so we can restrict our domain to $[0,1]$.
Then as you have done, use a trigonometric substitution, but then write it as
$$\sqrt{3^2 + 7^2 - 2(3)(7)\cos\theta}+\sqrt{7^2 + 10^2 - 2(7)(10)\cos(\tfrac\pi2-\theta)}.$$
The image you should draw is a point $P$, a point $A$ such that $PA=10$, a point $C$ such that $PC=3$ and $\angle APC$ is a right angle, and a point $B$ such that $PB=7$ and $B$ lies on the interior of $\angle APC$.
We want to minimize $AB + BC$, which will happen when $B$ lies on $\overline {AC},$ making
$$AB + BC = AC = \sqrt{3^2 + 10^2} = \sqrt{109}$$

A dupe was mentioned in the comments. This answer is better than any of the options posted there!

I solved it this way right before looking at it! Thank you for the amazing solution :)
